# Find an unbound sequence in which $a_{n+1}$ - $a_n$ converges to zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find an unbound monotonic increasing sequence in which $a_{n+1}$ - $a_n$ converges to zero.

I've been thinking about this one for a while. found it in an exam from seven years ago.
I don't know if the answer is hidden in some rule we've learned or are we just expected to be creative.

Comment: Yes, you are expected to be creative. I guess that is, at least in part, what exams are for.

Comment: So how do i get to such an answer?
I mean, it's easy to just read it off the internet but how do i get to the thought process?

Comment: @Agami The simplest "natural" examples of sequences that increase monotonically and might satisfy your requirements are (i) sequences diverging to infinity "slowly enough" (if it goes too fast, then the difference between two terms may not go to zero); and (ii) series with non-negative terms that diverge, but not trivially (i.e., general term going to zero). The two lead to basically the same examples, or almost; but for (i), divergence is easy to show, the key to control is the difference between terms going to zero; for (ii), it's more or less the opposite...

Comment: Thinking of (i) is heuristic: you want something going to infinity, but not too fast -- $\ln n$ is a natural choice, it's the textbook example of slow divergence. For (ii), once you phrase is that way, classic examples should come to mind: pick you favorite diverging series with non-negative terms ($\sum_n 1/n^a$ for $0 < a \leq 1$, for instance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence $a_n = \sqrt{n}$ is unbounded and monotonic increasing with

$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} \to 0.$$

Answer (score 7):

What about a divergent series with positive terms -- the most infamous being the harmonic series?
$$
H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
$$
(It is a classic result that it goes to infinity roughly like $\ln n$; and $(H_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is clearly a monotone increasing sequence, while $\frac{1}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$.)

Answer (score 3):

$a_n = ln(n)$. The difference $a_{n+1}-a_n = ln(n+1)-ln(n)= ln(\frac{n+1}{n})$ converges to zero as $\frac{n+1}{n}$ converges to 1.